# li:odd li:even not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this piece of code in my Wordpress theme:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $ ('ul li:even').addClass('even');
            $ ('ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
        });
</script>
```

and in the body part

```
<div id="specs">
<ul>
<li><strong>Standby Time</strong> 1100hr</li>
<li><strong>Internal Storage</strong> 16GB or 32GBGB</li>
<li><strong>Memory Slot</strong> microSD up to 32GB</li>
<li><strong>Camera</strong> 8 Megapixel</li>
<li><strong>Front Facing Camera</strong> 2 Megapixel</li>
<li><strong>Video Camera</strong> Yes, 1080p</li>
<li><strong>Camera Flash</strong> 1 x LED</li>
<li><strong>Coverage (Band)</strong> Quad</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The jQuery doesn't seem to apply odd and even classes. Tried with different versions of jQuery but still nothing. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: First thought: are you sure that the jQuery library's being loaded; because otherwise [your posted html/jQuery works](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WFkTf/). Have you styled the `.odd` and `.even` rows differently?

Comment: Anything in the error console? How are you determining that it hasn't worked? Your DOM inspector (Firebug / Chrome Developer Tools) should show the added classnames on the elements

Comment: @David - Yes I am sure because I am using other jQuery scripts on the page.

Comment: @Phil $ is not a function
http://localhost/wichelectronics/samsung-galaxy-s-ii/#specs
Line 65

Comment: @Andrei Then jQuery has not been loaded

Comment: It does appear to work http://jsfiddle.net/evMNf/2/

Comment: If you think that jQuery is loaded (I'm pretty sure it isn't...), you could always try to use plain JavaScript to be sure that it's not a browser error, bug, or something: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WFkTf/1/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work just fine, but we can also try to rewrite it a bit to also use the best practice of the `:even` and `:odd`-selectors according to the jQuery docs:

> **Additional Notes**:
>
> Because :even is a jQuery extension and not part of
>   the CSS specification, queries using :even cannot take advantage of
>   the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. To achieve the best performance when using :even to select
>   elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then
>   use .filter(":even").

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('ul li').filter(':even').addClass('even').end()
              .filter(':odd').addClass('odd');
});
```

Checklist:

1. Is jQuery loaded? (Check you network monitor in Firebug/Chrome)
2. Do you need the `ul` filter in the first selector? Selecting on just `li` would be even more performant since jQuery could utilize `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: Do you really want the semi-colon at the end of your first line?

Comment: Perhaps he doesn't want it to effect `<ol>` items

Comment: @DavidThomas Nope, edited that a few minutes back :) Thanks though!

Comment: @Phil That's why I said "do you need". I didn't say "remove the ul selector", now did I? :)

Answer (score 3):

That jQuery code works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/V2Nk7/

I'm guessing that jQuery is not being properly included in your page, check the `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` is outputing, I would wager that it is causing a malformed URL and the script tag is 404ing.

Answer (score 0):

its working here http://jsfiddle.net/7ppTM/

make sure jquery is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jQuery has either not been loaded correctly or there's a conflict using `$` (Prototype?).

What does the jQuery `<script>` line look like when you view source?

If it is a library conflict, try changing this line

> $(document).ready(function() {

to

```
jQuery(function($) {
```

Also, as (was) indicated in a comment, you can achieve this effect purely using CSS. See http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

Comment: Progressive enhancement. IE users are oblivious to what they're missing out on ;)

Comment: I second your comment. Just something to be aware of. =)

Answer (score -2):

You've got an unecessary space between $ and the brackets. Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('ul li:even').addClass('even');
        $('ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
    });
```

Comment: Yes, the space is unneccessary, but it is not invalid code. Just like `function(){}` and `function (  ) { }` are equivalent.